# Local server logs in putty

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, logging, console

Can we see local server(Tomcat) logs in Putty?? Now I am seeing the logs in java console, and please suggestion on good GUI to see the tomcate server logs excluding the eclipse.

Thank you

Comment: Why excluding Eclipse? Have you already tried the Eclipse Remote Connections?

Answer (score 1):

Open a shell on the server and cd to the Tomcat log directory.  Now use "tail -f logfile" to see in real-time what is being written to that logfile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use programs like [mtail](http://ophilipp.free.fr/op_tail.htm) on windows or a simple tail on linux to have a better view